# Spring Data findById (HashKey) hang

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I have a component(A) pom that refers 2 common component.
One common component B that has all AWS DynamoDB configurations.
Other common component C that has all Kinesis Client Lib configuration

Component A is spring boot application and when I start as a Kinesis client consumer, the application starts without any issue.

When I send a request in the Kinesis stream, the requested event is consumed and we lookup DynamoDB based on the hashkey passed on the event. 
I could see the SimpleDynamoDBPagingAndSortingRepository is loading proper and fetching values from DB but the control never returns to my method (from my application side the control simply hangs). 
I could see a looping of multicast event happening internally in spring but not clear why.

```
    @Id
@DynamoDBHashKey
private String key;
```

My POM dependencies are

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli)  ---
[INFO] com.myteam.project:request-processor:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.myteam.project:common-component:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +-com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.spring-data-dynamodb:spring-data-dynamodb:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |     +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |     +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.myteam.components:kinesis-client-library-component:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.306:compile
[INFO] +- com.twilio.sdk:twilio:jar:7.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.21.0:test
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
```

Are there any conflicts with Spring jar based on my dependency metrics?
Not sure why no exception is thrown back in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
Looks like, if we start Kinesis Worker as part of main thread, Spring data gets blocked while trying to synchronize on an object to multicast the "AfterLoad" event from DB.
I had to start the Kinesis worker in a separate thread to fix this.
Resolution is updated here 
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/201